# GeoServer GetCapabilities Not Working

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, geoext

I am trying to learn how to use the OpenGeo suite by following the tutorials on the site. The one I'm currently trying to follow is http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/stores/capabilities.html.
Most of it works, but I can't get the grid to populate with the layers from GeoServer. This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GeoExt Workshop Application</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script src="openlayers/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="geoext/lib/GeoExt.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = "ext/resources/images/default/s.gif";
        var app, items = [], controls = [];

        Ext.onReady(function() {
            app = new Ext.Viewport({
                layout: "border",
                items: items
            });
        });

        items.push({
            xtype: "gx_mappanel",
            ref: "mapPanel",
            region: "center",
            map: {
                numZoomLevels: 19,
                controls: controls
            },
            extent: OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray([
                -122.911, 42.291,
                -122.787,42.398
            ]),
            layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Medford",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
                {layers: "medford"},
                {isBaseLayer: false}
            )]
        });
        controls.push(
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.PanPanel(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel()
        );

        items.push({
            xtype: "grid",
            ref: "capsGrid", // makes the grid available as app.capsGrid
            title: "Available Layers",
            region: "north",
            height: 150,
            viewConfig: {forceFit: true},
            store: new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&",
                autoLoad: true
            }),
            columns: [
                {header: "Name", dataIndex: "name", sortable: true},
                {header: "Title", dataIndex: "title", sortable: true},
                {header: "Abstract", dataIndex: "abstract"}
            ],

            bbar: [{
                text: "Add to Map",
                handler: function() {
                    app.capsGrid.getSelectionModel().each(function(record) {
                        var clone = record.clone();
                        clone.getLayer().mergeNewParams({
                            format: "image/png",
                            transparent: true
                        });
                        app.mapPanel.layers.add(clone);
                        app.mapPanel.map.zoomToExtent(
                            OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(clone.get("llbbox"))
                        );
                    });
                }
            }]
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been playing around on firebug to try to figure out what's going on, particularly on the request

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&
```

since this is the request that is supposed to get the layer info.
The request header it sends is below. The response for some reason is 0 bytes. I'm not very familiar with web development, but I thought this should be a GET request instead of an OPTIONS request.

```
OPTIONS /geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1& HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.8)
```

What is going wrong? And how can I fix it?

EDIT: Here is part of the log file, which includes starting up OpenGeo and then loading the webpage I built in the tutorial. The rest is just the requests for the map tiles that look like

```
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:52 +0000] "GET /geoserver/wms?LAYERS=medford&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-122.87109375,42.36328125,-122.8271484375,42.4072265625&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256 HTTP/1.1" 200 6993
```

I went over the character limit by including them so I took them out.

```
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "HEAD /dashboard/version.ini HTTP/1.1" 200 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces.json HTTP/1.1" 200 685 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/AENVTest/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 155 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/AENVTest/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/medford/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 262 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/medford/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 178 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/earth/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 268 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/earth/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 166 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 146 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/usa/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 148 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/usa/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/analytics/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 138 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:44 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/analytics/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:44 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/world/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 252 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:44 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/world/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:44 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/layers.json HTTP/1.1" 200 3036 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:44 +0000] "GET /geoexplorer/maps/ HTTP/1.1" 200 556 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:45 +0000] "HEAD /dashboard/version.ini HTTP/1.1" 200 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:48 +0000] "HEAD /dashboard/version.ini HTTP/1.1" 200 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:50 +0000] "HEAD /dashboard/version.ini HTTP/1.1" 200 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:52 +0000] "OPTIONS /geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "HEAD /dashboard/version.ini HTTP/1.1" 200 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces.json HTTP/1.1" 200 685 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/AENVTest/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 155 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/AENVTest/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/medford/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 262 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/medford/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 178 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/earth/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 268 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/earth/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 166 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 146 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/usa/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 148 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/usa/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/analytics/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 138 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/analytics/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/world/datastores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 252 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/world/coveragestores.json HTTP/1.1" 200 21 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoserver/rest/layers.json HTTP/1.1" 200 3036 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:53 +0000] "GET /geoexplorer/maps/ HTTP/1.1" 200 556 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [23/Jan/2013:18:10:55 +0000] "HEAD /dashboard/version.ini HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Comment: what is in the log file

Comment: When I open the web page, nothing is added to the log on the OpenGeo Dashboard. Do you mean that log, or is it something else?

Comment: look in the logs folder of your jetty install

Comment: The file keepme.txt found in C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\OpenGeo Suite\logs is empty, and is the only file in the folder.

Comment: I suspect that means that you haven't started Jetty up, as I'm pretty sure it always logs something on start up.

Comment: The tutorial did not mention anything about Jetty, and I'm just starting with OpenGeo and web development, so I'm not really sure what this means. I'm assuming it should be running?

Comment: I found the log file in the .geoserver folder and added it to the question.

Comment: Looks like the server is not responding. Copy/paste http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1 into address bar in browser and see if you can get a response.

Comment: Can you fix the problem??? I've the same. when I use geoserver and i try to put "new conexion WMS" in the url ex:http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities that show me this error:" Prueba de conexión fallida: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS " I read other tutorials and its looks like is a problem of autentication....

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If your OpenLayers script is not on `http://localhost:8080/` and your browser or server does not support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), that is your problem.

Comment: My code is in a html file called map.html, which I simply double click to open, so unless it's running on port 80, I'm not sure where its running. Firebug says the domain of the option request is localhost:8080 and gives the remote IP as 127.0.0.1:8080. I'm also assuming I need to set up a proxy, but I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: You could open your application through Jetty (from localhost:8080), then you won't need proxy. Sorry, haven't done this myself, and can't give any instructions.

Comment: Don't double click the file - type the address of the web page with your map in it into your browser. It should start http://localhost:8080/geoserver/...

Comment: Where should I be storing the file for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kinds of solution based on my experience:

1. js problem: copy your code in jetty web app beside your GeoServer for solving js security problem
2. GeoServer problem: after solving problem in 1, if does not work, your Layers in GeoServer is not complete. for example if one of your Layers does not have 'Style' your code does not work